# Tailwind Flex Box Responsive Grid with Cards issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Here is where i started with

Preview

[image]

Code :

```
<div class="container my-12 mx-auto">
            <div className="flex flex-wrap ">
              {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
              {!isLoading ? (
                users.map(user => {
                  const { username, name, email } = user;
                  return (
                    <div
                      key={username}
                      className="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3  my-5"
                    >
                      <article class="overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg">
                        <img
                          alt="Placeholder"
                          className="block h-auto w-full"
                          src="https://picsum.photos/600/400/?random"
                        />
                        <header class="flex items-center justify-between leading-tight p-2 bg-white invisible lg:visible">
                          <h1 class="text-lg">{name}</h1>
                          <p class="text-grey-darker text-sm">
                            {email}
                          </p>
                        </header>
                      </article>
                    </div>
```

Then i tried to make it more spaced out like shown in the codepen example here : 
https://codepen.io/codetimeio/pen/RYMEJe

but everytime i try to add some padding and margin it escapes to the next line and i cant figure out why it does that or how i can stop it

[image]

Here is the line i updated :

```
<div key={username} className="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3  my-5 mx-5">
```

Here is my tailwind config file

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true
    },
    screens: {
      sm: "640px",
      md: "768px",
      lg: "1024px",
      xl: "1280px"
    },
    fontFamily: {
      display: ["Gilroy", "sans-serif"],
      body: ["Graphik", "sans-serif"]
    },
    extend: {}
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
};
```

I really want to understand what im doing wrong so that i can use tailwind as my main templating framework

---

Here is updated code as per the given answer below

```
<div class="container my-12 mx-auto bg-gray-400">
            <div className="flex flex-wrap ">
              {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
              {!isLoading ? (
                users.map(user => {
                  const { username, name, email } = user;
                  return (
                    <div key={username} className="w-full p-5 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3">
                      <article className="overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg">
                        <img alt="Placeholder" className="w-full" src="https://picsum.photos/600/400/?random" />
                        <header className="flex items-center justify-between leading-tight p-2 bg-white">
                          <h1 className="text-lg">{name}</h1>
                          <p className="text-grey-darker text-sm">
                            {email}
                          </p>
                        </header>
                      </article>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because of the extra margins, `w-1/3` means ~ `width: 33.3333%` If you add a margin on top of it, three can't fit in one line.

There are alternative ways (widths taking into account the gutter or [gap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)), but in exactly this case you could just use padding instead of margins, because you already have a presentational wrapping element around your cards.

Example: https://codepen.io/tlgreg/pen/RmLMOx

Not related, but few notes looking at your code:

- Unless you use the old color palette in the config, `grey-darker` will not work.
- `img` is `block` by default in v1.
- `invisible` and `lg:visible` changes `visibility`, the header will take up space, if that not what you want, it should be `hidden` and `lg:flex`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, i tried using your structure and still faced the same issue....here is the screenshot https://imgur.com/fa92MIp  - added updated code above